# Bitmap Loading Breaks When Switching to Vectors over Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, image, vector

In a recent change to switch my program from using arrays to vectors when creating a buffer, a totally unrelated problem surfaced. This switch involves the creation of a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<GLfloat> > > terrainMap;` instead of a `GLfloat[size+1][size+1][4] terrainMap`.  To initialize the 3-D vector, I use

```
 terrainMap.resize(size+1);
for (int i = 0; i < size+1; ++i) {
    terrainMap[i].resize(size+1);

    for (int j = 0; j < size+1; ++j)
      terrainMap[i][j].resize(4);
    }
```

This "map" is a parameter of many classes which modify the contents as setup for the program through `void Terrain::Load(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<GLfloat> > >& terrainMap,State &current){` This is the strange part though, when creating a totally unrelated bitmap for for texturing, a break point is hit and going further results in heap corruption. Here is the code for the image loading.

```
bmp = LoadBmp("dirt.jpg");
```

which extends into...

```
Bitmap Object::LoadBmp(const char* filename) {
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap::bitmapFromFile(ResourcePath(filename));
bmp.flipVertically();
return bmp;
}
```

at this point bmp is the proper 1600 by 1600 size with the correct format, RGB. It is, however, the following that causes the malfunction.

```
Bitmap& Bitmap::operator = (const Bitmap& other) {
_set(other._width, other._height, other._format, other._pixels);
return *this;
}


void Bitmap::_set(unsigned width, 
              unsigned height, 
              Format format, 
              const unsigned char* pixels)
{
if(width == 0) throw std::runtime_error("Zero width bitmap");
if(height == 0) throw std::runtime_error("Zero height bitmap");
if(format <= 0 || format > 4) throw std::runtime_error("Invalid bitmap format");

_width = width;
_height = height;
_format = format;

size_t newSize = _width * _height * _format;
if(_pixels){
    _pixels = (unsigned char*)realloc(_pixels, newSize);
} else {
    _pixels = (unsigned char*)malloc(newSize);
}

if(pixels)
    memcpy(_pixels, pixels, newSize);
}
```

the image finds its way to `_pixels = (unsigned char*)realloc(_pixels, newSize);` where the content of _pixels points to unreadable memory. 
What strikes me as strange is how changing the 3-D array to a 3-D vector causes this problem. No interaction between the two is occurring. Any help is much appreciated.
Behemyth

Comment: How about supplying class *definitions* rather than just a triple-dim vector. An [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) would really come in handy. Further, that triple-dim vector will assuredly NOT be storing all allocation in one contiguous block, so any thoughts you can either read, or write, it as if it were will *not* work. Finally, is there a solid constructor-definition that ensures `_pixels` is NULL when it is associated to an uninitialized or zero-sized bitmap? If not, you're calling `realloc()` with a bogus pointer. If so, the test itself is pointless; realloc() will work with NULL correctly.

Comment: Your call to `realloc` is wrong. If `realloc` fails you have a memory leak because you lost the original pointer. Assign the return value to a temp, check for NULL, and then assign to `_pixels`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the pixel data in a contiguous buffer, that means you need to have *one* `std::vector<GLfloat>` of size `_width * _height * _format` and not vectors of vectors.

Using `vector` instead of an array won't save you from the index arithmetic.  It will save you from memory leaks like the one Ed S. pointed out in a comment.  And it will allow you to get rid of your assignment operator entirely, since the compiler-provided default copy assignment (and move assignment) operator will work great.